# Using Jquery fadeOut() how can hide this Msg box

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to close(*fadeout*) the message box when i click the close button. But here it is not working. help me to fix this.

before it close automatically. if i click the close button the message box should hide. but here it is not working

Here is my [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/rxR5E/6/)

Here is my script;

```
$('.msg_close_icon_div').click(function(){
    $('.error_msgbox').fadeOut('slow');    
});

$('.error_msgbox').hide().fadeIn('slow').delay(4500).fadeOut('slow');
```

if user not click the close button(*it is there in topright corner*) then i want to close the message box automatically after 3sec.
​

Comment: Working here bruv: http://jsfiddle.net/QqyNC/2/ ; might be check your javascript include, cheers!

Comment: before it close automatically if i click the button it is not hide

Comment: I think what you are seeing is the `fadeIn` is in progress when you click.  Look at the events and detect if an animation is in progress when you click, prior to your fadeOut in the click event handler.

Comment: @Tats_innit before it close automatically. if i click the close button the message box should hide. but here it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setTimeout() will help to solve this problem:

Here is the script:

```
$('.msg_close_icon_div').click(function(){
    $('.error_msgbox').fadeOut('slow');    
}); 


setTimeout(function(){ jQuery(".error_msgbox").hide(); }, 7000);
```

Example is here **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/rxR5E/8/)**

**[More setTimeout() Examples](http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/settimeout-example/#.T89YJ7Bo3Zc)**

Answer (score 0):

You have not selected jQuery plugin onload in your fiddle

Check working fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/rxR5E/3/

Comment: before it close automatically if i click the button the message should hide but in your it is not hiding

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide the div manually since your holding up the queue with the delay(). The delay() function is flawed in that it can't be canceled, which is actually mentioned in the [jQuery manual](http://api.jquery.com/delay/).

Remove the delay() and the click() function will work as expected. If you still need the timing event I recommend a different approach, perhaps an ordinary setTimeout() or use the more appropriate queue() function available in jQuery (http://api.jquery.com/queue/).

You should also modify your current code since it produces a [FOUC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content)!